# Raycasting. Corner trap

Tags: java, libgdx, raycasting, steering-behaviors, cornering

In my top-down game character moves to target (pathfinding) also avoiding obstacles with *Raycasting*(Central ray with whiskers), but situation like on picture causes shiver and unneeded turning (problem similar to corner trap). Even if the whiskers angle is small (0.2 rad). How to deal with it?

[image: Picture]

**EDIT:**

Added more exact picture. I'm using Priority steering and if Raycast steering is not zero, it wins. 
[image]

Comment: I do not really understand the problem you see with the raycasting. If one whisker hits an obstacle, you normally evade the other way (where nothing stands in the way). So this would result in a small shiver, but my understanding does not match your picture.
As useful resource I recommend this article: http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/

Comment: @Kronos , I've edited the question so please look there. And this link, I saw it many times, but it tells only about circle obstacles.

Comment: You're overthinking this. Just use A* pathfinding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: I just realized that someone necroposted this.

Comment: @Krythic No such thing as necroposting on SE :) And it's the Stack Exchange bot who bumped it; it's an automatic process to bring visibility to some questions that could need additional answers or upvotes to current answers.

Answer (score 1):

In the example of yours, seames that right whisker hits obstacle. In that case you must do a little strade left. In general you must elaborate evasion depending on central and lateral rays hits.

Comment: So you mean if whisker steers totally away frow target (nearly 90 degrees) just ignore it? Also I've just had an idea to make all corners obtuse (but probably it will lower the performance)